# Django Form save - circular dependency

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have 2 models Account and User. An Account can have multiple users.

When the first User(Owner) is created at the same time the Account will be created.

Because User have a ForeignKey to Account, I need first to create the Account, and after the User.

But Account had a field created_by which is request.user. So is a circular problem.

I think I need to create first the Account and created_by to be a superuser(first) and than create the User, and update the Account with the new user.

```
class Account(MetaData):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
created_by = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, blank=True,
                                   related_name='%(app_label)s_%(class)s_created_by', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    account = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, blank=True, null=True, related_name='owner')
```

How can I do that ?

I need this only first time, for the first user, because after that for the other users the Account will exist.

When I'm saying first user, I'm not referring to staff users (as superusers), but normal users for which an account is mandatory thru a register form.

`blank=True` is just for staff members.

Comment: just a note, not a solution: in the code above, `account` field on `User` model is pointing to `User` (not `Account`) assuming `AUTH_USER_MODEL` is `User`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `User` model's `account` field allows nulls, so nothing prevents you from first creating the user without an account, then creating the account with this user, and finally updating the user with the account:

```
 with transaction.atomic():
     user = User.objects.create(account=None, ...)
     account = Account.objects.create("test", created_by=user)
     user.account = account
     user.save(update_fields=["account"])
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it's only a problem for the first user, you might want to [override the method `create_superuser` of the manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.models.CustomUserManager) to add the account. Also, since you've defined the `ForeignKey`s with `null=True`, it should not be a problem to first create a superuser (using `super().create_superuser()`) and then create the `account` and attach it to the superuser.

When deploying your site the first time, you'll have to manually run the `./manage.py createsuperuser` command.

Comment: when I'm saying first user, I'm not referring to staff users (as superusers), but normal users for which an account is mandatory

Comment: ah ok, that wasn't clear. Then the other answer fits the problem.